# Puppet Class Dependencies within Modules

Tags: puppet, sensu

Currently, I am writing a puppet module for managing my sensu configuration.

Have split the whole thing into several classes and put them into their respective files in the sensu "manifests" directory:

```
sensu::common          (common.pp)
sensu::common::package (common/package.pp)
sensu::common::config  (common/config.pp)
sensu::server          (server.pp)
sensu::server::config  (server/config.pp)
```

In my `server.pp`, I have the following

```
class sensu::server {
  include sensu::common
  include sensu::server::config

  Class['sensu::common'] -> Class['sensu::server::config']
}
```

And the `nodes.pp` looks like this:

```
class role_monitoring_server {
  $my_role = 'monitoring_server'
  ...
  include sensu::server
}

node my_cool_server {
  include role_monitoring_server
}
```

As most of you might have guessed, I have trouble with the class dependency in `server.pp`:

```
Class['sensu::common'] -> Class['sensu::server::config']
```

just does not work. The class `sensu::server::config` needs to place a file in a directory, that will only be created by `sensu::common`. The thing is, that `sensu::server::config` will always be applied before `sensu::common`and not after as expected.

What do I miss? There are so many questions out there on the web but I just don't find an answer, since I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a dependency relationship with the `sensu::common` class, but there's no implicit dependency relationship between `sensu::common` and its "children", `package` and `config`.  So, unless your config looks otherwise (I'm assuming the `sensu::common` class is just a couple `include` lines?) those are still free to be applied at any time in relation to the `sensu::server::config` class.

You'll probably want to build the relationship with the class that contains the resources that you need; you're effectively creating a require relationship each resource in one class to each resource in the other (whichever one of these is needed, or both):

```
Class['sensu::common::package'] -> Class['sensu::server::config']
Class['sensu::common::config'] -> Class['sensu::server::config']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shane! You solution works and the resources get applied in the right order.

Comment: Apart from the includes in `common.pp`, I have the following relationship `Class['sensu::common::package'] -> Class['sensu::common::config']`.  So, I thought that this would ensure somehow the resources defined in them will get applied first. Where is the problem in my thinking?

Comment: @Tobias That builds the relationship between those two, but the `common` class itself still isn't actually involved in the dependency chain.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. Just out of curiosity: What if I write `Class['sensu::common::package'] -> Class['sensu::common::config'] -> Class[sensu::common]`. Does that make sense? At least it won't work. Just have tried it. Got the error message, that sensu::common can't be found ... Anyways, will stick to your solution and thanks a lot again!